# Correct way of implementing if else loop or else if and can i write function inside a loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function toltalRetailerComm($userId) {
    //print_r ($shoppeId);
    $sql = "SELECT shoppe_id FROM atm_super_shoppe WHERE user_id='$userId'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $query->row();
        $shoppeId = $result->shoppe_id;

        $sql = "SELECT COALESCE(sum(commission),0) as commission FROM atm_shoppe_commission WHERE shoppe_id ='$shoppeId'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        print_r($shoppeId);
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $result = $query->row();
            $commission = $result->commission;
            return $commission;
        } else {
```

> Blockquote block2

```
            $sql = "SELECT shoppe_id FROM atm_store WHERE user_id='$userId'";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $result = $query->row();
                $storeId = $result->shoppe_id;
                $sql = "SELECT COALESCE(sum(commission),0) as commission FROM atm_store_commission WHERE shoppe_id ='$storeId'";
                $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                print_r($storeId);
                if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
                    $result = $query->row();
                    $commission = $result->commission;
                    return $commission;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to PHP, can anyone tell me the correct way of using an `if/else` or `elseif` in the code shown above? Its not able to go to the second block. Also and can I write a function inside an `if/else` block?

Comment: You have 1 $query->num_rows() and the others as $query->num_rows is this a typo or intentional?

Comment: Why is it sometimes `$query->num_rows` and sometimes `$query->num_rows()`?

Comment: Tim, this isn't an answer, it should be a comment (and someone has already commented that)

Comment: I would have happily commented it if it were possible too but I see no ability to comment against the main question. And for the record when I started typing this there was no other comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
function toltalRetailerComm($userId) {
    //print_r ($shoppeId);
    $sql = "SELECT shoppe_id FROM atm_super_shoppe WHERE user_id='$userId'";
    $shoppe_query = $this->db->query($sql);

    $sql = "SELECT shoppe_id FROM atm_store WHERE user_id='$userId'";
    $store_query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($shoppe_query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $shoppe_query->row();
        $shoppeId = $result->shoppe_id;

        $sql = "SELECT COALESCE(sum(commission),0) as commission FROM atm_shoppe_commission WHERE shoppe_id ='$shoppeId'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        print_r($shoppeId);
        if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
            $result = $query->row();
            $commission = $result->commission;
            return $commission;
        }
    } else if ($store_query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $result = $store_query->row();
                $storeId = $result->shoppe_id;
                $sql = "SELECT COALESCE(sum(commission),0) as commission FROM atm_store_commission WHERE shoppe_id ='$storeId'";
                $query = $this->db->query($sql);
                print_r($storeId);
                if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
                    $result = $query->row();
                    $commission = $result->commission;
                    return $commission;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: yup similar to it...but it wont fetch the storeID                                 else if ($store_query->num_rows() > 0) {
                $result = $query->row();
                $storeId = $result->shoppe_id;

Comment: thanks jimy.... but suppose i got several functions and i need to use the same store_id and shoppe_id for different functions ...how to achive it

Comment: You can pass them in function parameters or make them global variables (not recommended) if u need to pass variables to different function then u need to redesign it with OOP

Answer (score 1):

Each of your `if`s checks if there are any results from the query. If there are - the `if` section is executed. If not - the `else` section is executed (and if there is no `else`, nothing is executed).

As to your question about functions - you can't create a function inside an `if/else` block, but you can call a function from it. You create a function:

```
function total ($a, $b){
    return $a+$b;
}
```

and the you can call it from the `if` block:

```
if ($a==$b){
   $c = total ($a,$b);
}
```

*EDIT:* As to your question about not getting to the second block. Before the second block there is an `if` as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT COALESCE(sum(commission),0) as commission FROM atm_shoppe_commission WHERE shoppe_id ='$shoppeId'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        print_r($shoppeId);
        if ($query->num_rows > 0)
```

The `if` checks if any rows were returned from the sql query that is supposed to return the first nonnull expression that follows the condition `shoppe_id ='$shoppeId'` . Only if no rows are returned, it gets to the second block, which is the `else` of this condition.

Comment: like can i write a function toltal($user) inside a if else loop or else if